# How set the background Image for a section in UITableview?

Tags: uitableview

Hav a option to set background image or color to cell.

How can I suppose to do that for a section with number of rows and each row in the section will be in different color..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same by using delegate method of UITableView,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In this method, you can set individual UIView according to section. Moreover, you can set individual section's height by overriding...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```